# Laravel: multiple attributes

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

How can I put 2 `attributes` in this `function` with same path? like `$this->attributes['bg_image'],['display_image']`

```
public function getImageFullAttribute()
{
    return asset(db_image_url('source/upload/image/', $this->attributes['bg_image']));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this for multiple attributes

```
public function getImageFullAttribute()
{
    return asset(db_image_url('source/upload/image/', [$this->attributes['bg_image'],$this->attributes['display_image']]));
}
```

i hope you got your solution .